# Core Data: odd crash when getting data from store

Tags: ios, core-data, reference, entity-relationship, one-to-many

Hia, got a one to many relation for chars and items. one char can hold a specific item, same item can be used by others.
The CharInfo is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ItemInfo * slotEar;
```

CharInfo.slotEar is a reference to the item. It is optional, min count 1, max count 1 and delete rule Nulify.
ItemInfo is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* slotEar;
```

ItemInfo.slotEar is a reference to the char. It is optional, one to many and delete rule Nulify.

They are referencing to each other.
There is an additional class that works with the data. It does hold the reference as well and provide it for storing.

```
ItemInfo *slotEar;
```

CharInfo get created before saving like this:

When I save the CharInfo, I set the ItemInfo (from my structure) in the aproviate slot.

```
    CharInfo *charInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CharInfo" 
                      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
charInfo.slotEar = currentChar.slotEar;
```

Saving the context works.

When I try to load the CharInfo from store, it works most of the time from now. After relaunching he does crash at this line.

```
curentChar.slotEar = charInfo.slotEar;
```

If there was no item reference (nil) then all is fine.

Unfortunately the crash is more a halt. No error is given, he just stops at that line in the debugger and the green description next to the link says: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Seems something is wrong with the reference I save or the way how I try to take it from the CharInfo to my class. Any idea?

Screenshot added:
[image: XCode4 AppCrash]

Comment: Have you enabled NSZombieEnabled? Can you show us the call stack when the crash occurs?

Comment: I have NSZombiesEnabled. Let me take a screenshoot. Edit: here is the full size version that actually allows something to be read. http://www.codebaker.de/L1AppCrash.png

Comment: Sweet, a game! Alright, if you do not set the slotEar does it work? Is it just this property or is it just the first occurence and the app crashes?

Comment: A fan gimmick for a game. Nothing that will make money. :) If I set the slotEar to nil (no item was selected) the App dont crash. Same for all slots. Only the slots that refer to ItemInfo crash if a reference is there. I just looked inside the sqlite file. The reference from the char to the item is there. Question: Core Data maintains the one to many relation if one side is set, right? I don't need to tell the item that it got a char on the other end or? (Beside I am accessing the correct item from the reference on Char side, that should be enough)

Comment: Core Data does not created the Object that resides in the reference. Why?

Comment: nevermind it does. Changed the source to:    ItemInfo * myDummy= charInfo.slotEar;
    curentChar.slotEar = myDummy; (Save the ItemInfo reference in a pointer and put that pointer to the Class.) It is the second step that cause the trouble. Even can look in the object, the ItemInfo reference is stored there. Don't understand it, all went ok, so whats the problem?

Comment: Did you set the inverse of the entity? Have a look at [Inverse Relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW4) or [Build a Core Data App](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php)

Comment: Yes, they are set. Found something very strange, which I don't understand. Did add another property for testing. ItemInfo * myItem; The property does have setter or getter yet and was for testing things. Didn't get that far. For some reason, the app works now without crash. After 3-4 tries. it crash again. Same game. Ok, this is totally beyond me.

Comment: This is hard to debug from afar. Maybe extracting the model to a test app without much logic can help. If it crashes, remove entities and test them in isolation. Without more information I can't be of much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No bug with core data or the worker class ivars, but with an int array with 6 ints filled with 100 ints.